# Why does Netty use `Multiple producer single consumer` Queue?

Tags: netty

The Threading Model of Netty-4 is:
[image]

Every EventLoop(Thread) owns its own taskQueue, this queue is only operated by this EventLoop(Thread). then How the taskQueue of the EventLoop be operated by 'multiple producer'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can submit work from out side of the `EventLoop`. For example if you call `Channel.write(...)` from another thread it will be dispatched to the `EventLoop` for processing. Which means it will need to be put into the `Queue`, which requires it to be MPSC at least.